# How to add a user group for mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I need add a new user group for mediawiki. The new group has more permission than "User" group. How can i get it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the new group all you have to do is assign it some rights. Use `$wgGroupPermissions['group']['right'] = true;` in your LocalSettings.php. See [Manual:User Rights](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights) for all the options.